# Unknown definition for dependency using build option on Sencha CMD

Tags: extjs, build, dependencies, sencha-cmd

I have created an application with Cmd using ExtJS GPL 6.2

Then I created a new view using the command:

```
sencha generate view -base Ext.window.Window login.Login
```

The problem is that if I run a "sencha app build" command then I have the following error:

```
[ERR] Failed to resolve dependency Ext.window.Window for file TestSte2.view.login.Login
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.window.Window
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 3 seconds

[ERR] C:\programs\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.2.15\plugin.xml:333: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\programs\workspaces\TestSte2\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:386: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\programs\workspaces\TestSte2\.sencha\app\init-impl.xml:436: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.window.Window
[ERR] A log is available in the file "C:\programs\workspaces\TestSte2\sencha-error-20180109.log"
```

Can you help me to understand the cause?

Thanks
Stefano

Comment: It's possible that you have Modern toolkit application. The Ext.window.Window is in the classic only

Comment: You are right. I was building the application with both classic and modern toolkit and the error was related to modern toolkit. So now I compile only classic toolkit and it works (I don't need modern toolkit application in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was building the application with both classic and modern toolkit and the error was related to modern toolkit. 
So now I compile only with classic toolkit and it works (I don't need modern toolkit application in this case)

Comment: Sometimes developer can't cut out the modern part.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the author uses "universal" application, which contains "classic" and "modern" parts.
In this case, specific classes must be located in different directories.
To know this, checkout app.json: "classpath" block:

**${toolkit.name}/src** - means that your have "classic/src" and "modern/src" for your app classes.

So the clue is that Ext.window.Window class is located in wrong directory which is identified as modern toolkit;
This class and such classes like Ext.container.Viewport are absent in modern part of Ext and you need to correct your file structure.